# Full Stack developer assigned support task in new job

Tags: careers, job-description

I recently moved to a new job where initial days there was no work assigned to me. I asked the manager about this and also asked to team members they said this is how it works there is not sufficient work to distribute with in a team. So, in 5 months they shuffle me into 5 projects. Right now, I am working in the Testing pod to automate the manual work flow of Testers such as count verification when data is synced to an external system. I am not getting work that I would like to do. Would you please suggest what should I do? I am really confused right now.

Answer (score 4):

You asked your team and you asked your manager:

> they said this is how it works

And as a result:

> I am not getting work that I would like to do

The only option here is to look for a job where you *do* get work you like to do, because it is highly unlikely the company will suddenly change just for you.